# Discarding the nodes we're collecting over

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We find writing and maintaining Cypher queries to be a bit pain when it comes to collecting items. We often want to collect something and discard the original node. See the following as an example:

`MATCH (p)-[]-(c)
WITH p, collect(c) as c
RETURN p, c`

The above doesn't look too bad. The problem is the explicit naming of `p`, the field we want to keep. As we add more `MATCH` and `OPTIONAL MATCH` with aggregation, this becomes a maintainability nightmare. We cannot reorder `MATCH`/`WITH` pairs without also changing all the fields we reference. When we do a `collect`, we always want to discard the original node.

`WITH` has an `*` that can be used, but this will include the field we're collecting, and we cannot replace the value.

`MATCH (p)-[]-(c)
WITH *, collect(c) as c
RETURN p, c`

Is there a way to exclude something in a `WITH` statement without explicitly naming everything that should be included?
Something like the following?

`MATCH (p)-[]-(c)
WITH *, without(c), collect(c) as cs
RETURN p, cs`

Comment: Interesting case. I think that is worth considering as an extension of the cypher features.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this, and given how aggregations work in Cypher, I think it would cause far more headaches than it would cure.

Remember that aggregations only have meaning with respect to the non-aggregation columns which form a grouping key. I find the explicit inclusion of variables in WITH clauses to be invaluable, as it gives you at-a-glance understanding of what fields are in scope, which gives you the context for your aggregation columns.

Without this, you risk buggy behavior because there could be variables in scope you forgot to exclude, which will change the meaning and calculation of your aggregations.

Comment: We have bugs because we have to explicitly state everything that should be included. This is primarily when doing a simple collect `WITH collect(c) AS cs` where we want to drop the `c` but keep everything else. With a sequence of `OPTIONAL MATCH` that does collects, this is very tedious and error-prone.